# You cannot render a <Router> inside another <Router>. You should never have more than one in your app. How do I fix this error?

Tags: reactjs, router

This is app.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Navbar from './Component/Navbar';
import Login from './Component/Login';
import Register from './Component/Register';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Router>
        <Navbar />
        <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
        <Route path="/Login" component={Login} />
        <Route path="/Register" component={Register} />
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}

function Home() {
  return <h2>Home</h2>;
}

export default App;
```

This is index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import App from './App';

ReactDOM.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <App />
  </BrowserRouter>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

I have tried everything to solve this but it is still showing this error and my react app is blank
Like nesting router routes route. But anything is not working

Comment: Remove the `<Router>` in `App`. You probably meant to use `<Routes>`